# problem starting mariadb

Tags: mariadb

When I tried to start mariadb, I got:

```
[root]# systemctl start mariadb
Failed to start mariadb.service: Unit not found.
```

And I also got this message:

```
Package 1:mariadb-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by mysql-community-client-5.6.39-2.el7.x86_64 which is already installed
```

What should I do next?

Comment: try `systemctl start mysql`

Comment: Please demonstrate in the question that the unproven assumption in its title, that you have MariaDB installed and this is a problem _starting_ it, is actually correct.

Answer (score -1):

The mariadb service is called mysqld.

Try `systemctl start mysqld`

Edit: and even if you have mysql installed instead this solution will still work :)

Comment: No it is not.  Read [the doco](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/).  It is called [`mariadb`](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.3/support-files/mariadb.service.in) and the questioner was getting this part right.  Do you see why I want the questioner to demonstrate that MariaDB is actually installed in the first place, now?

Comment: Yes it is.  I've been running it for years.  Maybe not in all cases but certainly in many.  https://i.imgur.com/XYmSmFt.png